# How can I use a Smarty template from a Smarty template?

Tags: php, templates, smarty, templating

I've run into a funny problem. I need to use Smarty templates *within* a Smarty template.

Here is why. I use the same templates for various wiki websites, and each website has its own configuration. The configuration contains parts for the main template (such as changed titles and headings, etc).

Here is a simplified example. I've a file `topic-list.template.html` that's shared across all websites:

```
<div id="topics">
  <h1>{$h1}</h1>
  ...
</div>
```

As you can see, this template file contains an `<h1>` tag that can be customized for each website.

Then for each of the websites I've a configuration file that looks like this (simplified):

```
$config = [
  "h1-titles" => [
      "topics" => "Showing Topics in {\$category}"
  ]
];
```

As you can see the configuration file contains a Smarty template.

So when I render the `topic-list.template.html` file, I've to render the `$config['h1-titles']['topics']` first through `$smarty->fetch("string":$config['h1-titles']['topics'])`, and then assign it to `h1` Smarty variable. My simplified code looks like this:

```
$h1_tag = $smarty->fetch("string":$config['h1-titles']['topics']);
$smarty->assign('h1', $h1_tag);
$smarty->display('topic-list.template.html');
```

I wonder if I could somehow insert the `$config['h1-titles']['topics']` in the `topic-list.template.html` file automatically and then it have all rendered in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the docs on [String Template Resources](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.string.tpl). You will immediately notice that your `$smarty->fetch('string:…')` approach can also be done within a template: `{include file="string:…"}`

Comment: This is also cool. Eugene also suggests `{eval}` in his comment. I'll try your method and also Eugene's. I'm not sure which is best, but if they both work I'll have to choose one or another. :)

Comment: Ok, `{eval}` works. Now I'm going to try `{include}` approach. I'm thinking `{include}` might be better because it actually compiles the string template to a file, so Smarty wouldn't be evaluating the string every time it sees it!

Comment: There is a note on that page: "With a string: resource type, each unique string generates a compiled file. Smarty cannot detect a string that has changed, and therefore will generate a new compiled file for each unique string. It is important to choose the correct resource so that you do not fill your disk space with wasted compiled strings.". Since you are talking about strings that may change a lot(titles), eval look more useful to me.

Comment: Nice finding @Eugene. Perhaps it's better to use `{eval}` then afterall!

Comment: `{include file="eval:…"}` accomplishes the same thing. Note that compiling templates (which eval does on every invocation) is quite expensive. Unless you're actually facing issues with a high number of (comparably tiny) files, I wouldn't be too concerned about this. But the real question is: are you using caching and how often is that eval actually executed. If you're caching, eval might not be too harmful…

Comment: You may also be interested in the fact that (at least up to 3.1.10) every `{eval}` and `{include file="eval:"}` call will compile that template. so using `{eval var="foo"} {eval var="foo"}` will actually compile twice.

Comment: I converted the whole site to use `{eval}` and I notice that it has gotten slower. I've about 40-100 evals per page load. I haven't setup caching yet as it's pretty complicated, as I'm reusing the same codebase and the same templates for multiple sites. I use Smart 3.1.10 btw.

Comment: How many to-eval-headlines do you have and how often to they change? If they practically never change, you could generate a single template-file out of them. that way you can leverage the compile cache - and don't flood your file system with tiny files

Answer (score 1):

I believe that **{eval}** tag may help you:

*{eval} is used to evaluate a variable as a template. This can be used for things like embedding template tags/variables into variables or tags/variables into config file variables.*

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.eval.tpl

Comment: Nice finding Eugene. I'll try it out!

Comment: Eugene, take a look at discussion in @rodneyrehm's comment. It's `{eval}` vs. `{include}`.